# Android files with names starting with a period not showing up via USB

Tags: android, windows-10, usb, mtp

I know that the dot in the beginning makes the file manager assume that it's a hidden file.

My computer is Windows 10 and I have an Android device.

I created a file on my Android device that starts with a period for example:

.test.txt

If I use Samsung File Manager with show hidden files enabled, I'm able see the file. While on Windows, the folder option settings "Show hidden files, folders, and drives" is enabled and the file is not showing up.

I have also tried unchecking the option "Hide protected operating system files" just in case and it still doesn't show.

I have checked to make sure that it is not a conflict with Windows and created the file on Desktop and it's showing up fine and doesn't count as a hidden system file.

Is there a reason that the file doesn't show up via USB or a way to make it show up?

Comment: In which folder? Full parh please. More files which are not hidden in same folder show up?

Comment: @blackapps, I have placed it in the base "Internal Storage". But it applies to any path, even in Downloads folder.

Comment: @blackapps, if you transfer a file like ".test.txt" from Windows to Android via USB, it will display in File Explorer on Windows. But once you unplug the USB and plug it back in and navigate back to the Android folder, you can no longer see it on Windows. But you'll be able to see it as a "hidden system file" on Android's file manager.

Comment: If anything I said might be confusing, I can upload screenshots that might help show it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below solution.
On run type: cmd
(enter)
select USB drive: F:
(enter)
write: attrib -s -h /s /d *.* (enter and wait)

After loading completes, check for missing USB file again.